# Best way to join / sort two lists

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to figure out what would be the best / fastest way to accomplish next task.

There is a list of int:

{ 4, 1, 112, 78 }

and there is a list of objects:

object { Id, Date, Value }

Rules:

- {int list} contains Ids which are not sorted in any particular order
- {int list} contains unknown number of elements
- {object list} will always have only one Id occurrence in one particular day. There can be not one date with two same Ids (the list of object is already supplied like this). You could say that Id+Date represents a unique object.
- JOIN Part: one day could have 1...n items, where 'n' represents the number of elements in {int list}. Requirement is that in final result all days have 'n' Ids. So if the day 1/1/2014 does not have item with Id=42, then a new item will be added to this list with Value=0.
- SORT part: {object list} needs to be sorted by date, and then by Id, but the Id order must be the same as it is in {int list}.

What would be the best algorithm to accomplish this task? This is what I do currently:

```
// first I insert all the missing Ids
// to achieve this, I sorted lists so I now when to expect which Id
var orderedIntList = intList.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
var orderedObjectList = objectList.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(x => x.Id).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < totalRecords; i++)
{
    currentIndex = i % 4;
    currentId = orderedIntList[currentIndex];

    if (orderedObjectList.Count <= i || currentId != orderedObjectList[i].Id)
        orderedObjectList.Insert(i, new Object { Date = currentDate, Id = currentId });

        currentDate = orderedList[i].Date;
}

// then in order to have items sorted in original order, I use LINQ join
int counter = 0;
var aListWithIndex = activityIds.Select(x => new { Index = counter++, Id = x }).ToList();

return (from a in aListWithIndex
        join b in orderedObjectList on a.Id equals b.Id
        orderby b.Date, a.Index
        select b
       )
       .ToList();
```

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is. Your rule set pretty much tells you what you should implement. There is no such thing as the perfect algorithm. Important is that you get it working without bugs (unless you find yourself saying "yes, it is broken but at least it is fast"). If you are concerned about performance, use a profiler and a large dataset to see whether it would really be an issue...

Comment: There a better and worse algorythms, if not perfect, and I hoping to see the approaches. I have edited the question to explain the current one I am using.

Comment: Can the object list contain an id that isn't in the int list? Also, if what you have works and doesn't take too long (i.e. isn't a huge bottleneck in your program), why worry about it?

Comment: @JimMischel no it cannot contain an Id which is not in the int list. As for the "why bother if it works", I am always interested in better approach, if it exist. Learn the other way is enough reward itself.

Comment: just a short hint, you can take a look at the function Array.Sort(array keys, array values)

Comment: @user287107 what kind of benefit do you think Array.Sort will bring?

Comment: sorry I just read the part about the sorting, but you are more in doing a grouping and working with sets. For these tasks, have you taken a look at .ToLookup, .GroupBy and the class HashSet ?